# I'm having an Automation error 404 while trying to refresh activex listbox filledrange

Tags: excel, vba

I'm worikng on a project for my senior year project and I have to deal with the Activex controls for my userinterface. For deleting the single item in the listbox, I have written the code below.

When I debug the code, I'm having an "automation error 404" at the last part of my code:

```
With Worksheets("Solve").OLEObjects("ListBox1")
        .ListFillRange = .ListFillRange
End With
```

Here is my code:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim lastrow As Integer

lastrow = Sheets("SrData").Cells(Sheets("SrData").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this Sales Representative?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Delete Sales Representative") = vbYes Then

    For i = 2 To lastrow


        sheetcontrol = Sheets("SrData").Cells(i, 1)
        listcontrol = Sheets("Solve").ListBox1.List(Sheets("Solve").ListBox1.ListIndex)

        If sheetcontrol = listcontrol Then

            Sheets("SrData").Activate
            ActiveWorkbook.Names("SrDat").Delete

            Sheets("SrData").Rows(i).Select
            Selection.Delete

            Sheets("SrData").Range(Sheets("SrData").Cells(2, 1), Sheets("SrData").Cells(lastrow - 1, 3)).Select

            ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="SrDat", RefersTo:=Selection



            End If

    Next i

End If


With Worksheets("Solve").OLEObjects("ListBox1")
    .ListFillRange = .ListFillRange
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an solution for my problem here is my edited code.

```
Set s = Worksheets("Solve")
Set sd = Worksheets("SrData")
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim target As String
Dim sheetcontrol As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

target = s.ListBox1.List(s.ListBox1.ListIndex)
lastrow = sd.Cells(sd.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

If IsNull(ListBox1) Then

    MsgBox "You haven't selected an Sales Representative. Please Select one."

Else

    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this Sales Representative?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Delete Sales Representative") = vbYes Then

    For i = 2 To lastrow
         sheetcontrol = sd.Cells(i, 1)

         If sheetcontrol = target Then

            s.ListBox1.ListIndex = -1

            sd.Rows(i).Delete
            sd.Activate
            ActiveWorkbook.Names("SrDat").Delete
            Range("'SrData'!$A$2:$C$" & lastrow - 1).Name = "SrDat"
            s.Activate
        End If
     Next i
     End If

End If
refSr
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

in refSr part I'm doing the

```
    With Worksheets("Solve").OLEObjects("ListBox1")
        .ListFillRange = .ListFillRange
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try working with something like this:

```
For i = ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
            ListBox1.RemoveItem i
        End If
 Next i
```

Edit: then you can delete the row at your “Solve” sheet with your code and update listrange like this:

```
Private sub userform_initialize()
With Worksheets("Solve").Range("A2:A" & lastrow) '<-- change with your range
                Me.ListBox1.List = Application.Transpose(.Cells)
                Set listRng = .Cells
    End With 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes this could also work but ı should have to update my source sheet. this is why ı have done the way that ı used in the code. Also this still not solves my problem too. :(

Comment: Thanks for your answer again. But as I have mentioned in the description its an Activex listbox which is located in the worksheet, its not located in the userform. I've tried what you have suggested to me but it's not working for the Activex objects.